# How to set the id for the new created item with Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

The problem is that I cannot update a new created item, because on the server I receive no Id.

I am trying to learn Knockout, and I am not able to find a way to provide the Id to new created items.

I have an object with Id, and Name, using knockout I can make all Crud operations, but, after inserting a new item, if I try to change his name I am not able because that item has no Id value.

My question is: Every time when I add a new item I need to get a fresh collection of items back to the view, and rebind the view?

or, there is a way to another way to provide the Id to the new inserted items?

Here is my code:

```
function Person(id, name) {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable(id);
    self.nume = ko.observable(name);


}

function PersonVm() {
    var self = this;



self.Persons = ko.observableArray([]);


self.newPerson = ko.observable(new Person())
self.isModificare = false;

self.addPerson = function () {

    if (!self.isModificare) {
        $.ajax("/Person/AddPerson", {
            data: ko.toJSON({ Person: self.newPerson }),
            type: "post", contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) { alert(result.mesaj); }
        });
    } else {
        $.ajax("/Person/UpdatePerson", {
            data: ko.toJSON({ Person: self.newPerson }),
            type: "post", contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) { alert(result) }
        });
    }
    self.isModificare = false;


    if (!self.isModificare) self.Persons.unshift(self.newPerson());
    self.newPerson(new Person());


}
self.removePerson = function () {
    $.ajax("/Person/DeletePerson", {
        data: ko.toJSON({ Person: self.newPerson }),
        type: "post", contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (result) { alert(result) }
    });
    self.Persons.remove(self.newPerson());
    self.newPerson(new Person());


}

self.ModificaPerson = function (person) {        
    self.newPerson(person);
    self.isModificare = true;

}

$.getJSON("/Person/GetPersons", function (allData) {
    var mapPerson = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new Person(item.Id,item.Name) });
    self.Persons(mapPerson);
});
}

ko.applyBindings(new PersonVm());
```

**Edit:**

This is the view:

```
 <div class="input-group">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: newPerson().name">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click:addPerson">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" style="color:green"></span>
            </button>
        </span>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click:$root.removePerson">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="color:red"></span>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>



 <ul data-bind="foreach: Perons" class="list-group" id="content">
    <li class="list-group-item"  data-bind="text: name,click:$root.ModificaPerson"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you show your view where you have `addPerson` Binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two steps to get what you want:

1. Ensure that your "Person/AddPerson" Web service return the ID of the created object.
2. Change your update method so that it sets an ID on the newPerson property:

   ```
   $.ajax("/Person/AddPerson", {
       data: ko.toJSON({ Person: self.newPerson }),
       type: "post", contentType: "application/json",
       success: function (result) {
           self.newPerson().Id(result.Id);
       }
   });
   ```

Note that the above code supposes that your services returns a JSON object with an ID property named 'Id'.

Comment: I tried this but is not working, (yes I have the Id in the ajax response)

Comment: After inserting a new item, the controller is sending the Id  , but when I try to update the same item, The update action is sending  the item back to the controller only with name, and Id=0.

Comment: Can you show exactly what you are sending back from your controller and how you set id and name in success call back